# Как отправить значение тега radio на почту?

Tags: php, input, radio

Сразу скажу, ламер я полный, к делу. Пишу страницу - отзыв для компании. Задача отправить отзыв на почту, я реализовал отправку textbox'ов, но отправку radio не понимаю как реализовать. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь, заранее спасибо.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Оценка сервисного обслуживания</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Logo_Volkswagen.png">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form">

                <div class="contain_1" id="first">

                   <div class="text_first">
                      <p>
                         Оцените сервисное обслуживание
                      </p>
                   </div>   

                    <div class="all_smiles">
                      <p>
                         <div>
                              <input id="checkbox1" type="radio" name="opinion" value="Отлично" hidden>
                              <label for="checkbox1"><a href="#second"><img src="img/smile_1.svg" class="smile1"></a></label>
                         </div>
                      </p>  

                      <p>
                         <div>
                             <input id="checkbox2" type="radio" name="opinion" value="Средне" hidden>
                             <label for="checkbox2"><a href="#second"><img src="img/smile_2.svg" class="smile2"></a></label>
                         </div>
                      </p> 

                      <p>
                         <div>
                             <input id="checkbox2" type="radio" name="opinion" value="Плохо" hidden>
                             <label for="checkbox3"><a href="#second"><img src="img/smile_3.svg" class="smile3"></a></label>
                         </div>
                      </p> 
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="contain_2" id="second">

                   <div class="poll">

                          <div class="text_second">
                              Как Вас зовут?<label class="star">*</label>                   
                          </div>

                          <div >
                              <input class="textbox1" type="textbox" id="name" name="name"><br>
                              <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">Введите имя.</label>  
                          </div>

                          <div class="text_second">
                              Ваш телефон?<label class="star">*</label>
                          </div>

                          <div>         
                              <input class="textbox2" type="textbox" id="phone" name="phone"><br>
                              <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">Введите номер телефона.</label>
                          </div>

                          <div class="text_second">
                              Оставьте, пожалуйста, отзыв                   
                          </div>

                          <div >
                              <textarea class="textbox3" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                          </div>

                          <div class="div_button" id="button">
                              <a href="#third"><button id="button" class="button" type="submit" name="button">Отправить</button></a>
                          </div>

                   </div>

                </div>

    </form>         

    <div class="contain_3" id="third">

       <div class="snk">
          <p>
              Спасибо за Ваш отзыв!
          </p>

           <img class="last_pic" src="img/Logo_Volkswagen.jpg">

       </div>

    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/transition.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/error.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/send.js"></script>

   <script>
      jQuery(function($) {
       $("#phone").mask("+7(000)000-00-00", {
         placeholder: "+7(___)___-__-__",
        });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$opinion = $_POST['opinion']==="Отлично" echo "Отлично";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '****@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = '****'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('****@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('****@mail.ru');
$mail->addAddress('****@gmail.com');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Оценка обслуживания';
$mail->Body    = '' 'Оценка: ' .$opinion. '<br>Имя: ' .$name. '<br>Телефон: ' .$phone. '<br>Отзыв: ' .$message;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: 3index.html');
}
?>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $(this).find('input').val('');
            $('#form').trigger('reset');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ещё, если после изменения по ответу будут ошибки, поменяй значения SMTP на такие: `$email->Host       = "ssl://smtp.mail.ru";                   
  $email->Port       = 465;                                   
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Готовый код: 

`
<?php

$test = $_POST['test'];
$opinion = $_POST['opinion'];

        require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
        require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
        $mdemail = md5($email);
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = '***'; //login
        $mail->Password = '***'; //password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->setFrom('****'); 
        $mail->addAddress("***"); //куда 
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "test"; 
        $mail->Body = "
        Сообщение $test <br> 
        Оценка: $opinion";

// Результат
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo ' ';
        } else {
            echo ' ';
        }


?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="radio" name="opinion" value="Отлично">
    <label for="checkbox1">Отлично</label>
    <input id="checkbox2" type="radio" name="opinion" value="Средне">
    <label for="checkbox2">Средне</label>
    <input id="checkbox3" type="radio" name="opinion" value="Плохо">
    <label for="checkbox3">Плохо</label>
    <button name="go">Отправить</button>
</form>
[![Письмо на почте:][1]][1]
```

Comment: Применил предложенные вами изменения, к сожалению форма вовсе не приходит на почту.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, что передаётся в самой переменной `var_damp($opinion);` в течение дня попробую сам отправить через phpmailer, результат приложу.

Comment: Изменил ответ, у меня на почту успешно всё пришло, попробуйте код, приложенный сверху.

Comment: Снова здравствуйте, уже огромное спасибо, ваш код заработал, только вот оценка пришла пустая) В письмо можно прикрепить значение value тега radio?

Comment: Я разобрался, у меня к тегу radio привязана картинка(что бы человек при выборе оценки не на квадратик нажимал, а на картинку, так более красиво), так вот, если нажимать на картинку и потом отправить, оценка приходит пустая, но если сделать radio видимым и нажимать непосредственно на квадратик, а потом отправить, то оценка приходит как надо. В чем дело?)

Comment: Снова дополняю ответ, все заработало, целиком и полностью. Проблема была в том, что картинки привязанные к тегу radio одновременно служили ссылками, когда я убрал тег a href"#", сообщения начали приходить с оценкой. Спасибо вам большое, за уделенное время и за оказанную помощь)